# React updating state only after second click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to build a react app and have run into a bug I can't seem to fix. I have a context file with a `days` variable in it and a `data` object that depends on number of days. it looks like this:

```js
const DataContext = createContext({ days: 720, data: { timestamp: [], price: [], short_ma: [], long_ma: [], money: [], action: [] }, daysChangeHandler: (newDays) => { } })
export default DataContext

export const DataContextProvider = (props) => {
    const daysChangeHandler = (newDays) => {
        setDays(newDays, getNewData())

    }
    const getNewData = () => {
        getData(days).then(response => setData(response))
        console.log('NEW DATA')
    }

    const [days, setDays] = useState(720)
    const [data, setData] = useState({ timestamp: [], price: [], short_ma: [], long_ma: [], money: [], action: [] })

    return <DataContext.Provider
        value={{ days: days, data: data, daysChangeHandler: daysChangeHandler }}>
        {props.children}
    </DataContext.Provider>


}
```

`getData` triggers a call to a database and gets the data back, it works I tested it.

The app is wrapped in the `dataContextProvider`.

When a button is clicked, it looks like this:

```js
export default function NumberOfDays(props) {

const context = useContext(DataContext)

    const predefinedDaysHandler = (days) => {

        context.daysChangeHandler(days)
}
return <button className='submit-button' onClick={() => predefinedDaysHandler(0)}>Max</button>
}
```

Finally, this should be displayed in a rendered component looking like this:

```js
export default function DataChart(props) {
    const context = useContext(DataContext)
    
console.log(context.data)
return //rendered data here, the updated data should be displayed but is only on the second time I click the submit button
}
```

The problem is that I have to click twice on the submit button to get the updated data value?

I have tried using `useEffect` in the `DataContextProvider`:

```js
useEffect(()=>{
getNewData(days)
}, [days])
```

But it changes nothing.

Also, when I press the submit button the first time, the `console.log('NEW DATA')` gets triggered, but the data somehow does not get updated in the component that should display my data before the second click.

To be really clear, the data that is displayed is always the data from just before the last update. How do I change this?

## EDIT

Tried to replace `daysChangeHandler` with:

```js
const daysChangeHandler = (newDays) => {
        setDays(newDays)
        getNewData()
    }
```

but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Why you pass two arguments to this code `setDays(newDays, getNewData())`. state can only have one argument.

Comment: Also `getNewData` is async so it returns Promise. You probably need to add `await` before the call.

Comment: Thank you for your responses, so If I put `>then` it is not enough? And originally, `getNewData()` was inside of `daysChangeHandler`. Didn't work. The idea to have setState with a callback function comes from here: https://sentry.io/answers/forget-set-state-is-async/

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to call `useEffect` and set `days` as a dependency inside of context:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    getData(days).then(response => setData(response))
}, [days]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I make a mockup that is specific to your use case

### My implementation is this

You may go to **[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-forest-2lbhx?file=/src/App.js:0-276)** to interact my Demo. But the code is just below

**context.tsx file**

```
import { createContext, useState } from "react";

const mockUp = {
  days: 720,
  data: {
    timestamp: [],
    price: [],
    short_ma: [],
    long_ma: [],
    money: [],
    action: []
  },
  daysChangeHandler: (newDays) => {}
};

const DataContext = createContext(mockUp);
export default DataContext;

export const DataContextProvider = (props) => {
  const [days, setDays] = useState(720);
  const [data, setData] = useState(mockUp);

  const daysChangeHandler = (newDays) => {
    getNewData();
    setDays(newDays);
  };
  const getNewData = () => {
    // getData(days).then(response => setData(response))
    // getData(days) mock up
    Promise.resolve(mockUp).then((res) =>
      setData(() => ({ ...res, days: 370 }))
    );
    console.log("NEW DATA");
  };

  return (
    <DataContext.Provider
      value={{ days: days, data: data, daysChangeHandler: daysChangeHandler }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </DataContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

**DataChart.tsx**

```
import { useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import DataContext from "./context";

export default function DataChart(props) {
  const { data } = useContext(DataContext);
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("data chart", data);
  }, [data]);

  return null; //rendered data here, the updated data should be displayed but is only on the second time I click the submit button
}
```

**NumberOfDays.tsx**

```
import { useContext } from "react";
import DataContext from "./context";

export default function NumberOfDays(props) {
  const context = useContext(DataContext);

  const predefinedDaysHandler = (days) => {
    context.daysChangeHandler(days);
  };
  return (
    <button className="submit-button" onClick={() => predefinedDaysHandler(0)}>
      Max
    </button>
  );
}
```

**App.tsx file**

```
import { DataContextProvider } from "./context";
import DataChart from "./DataChart";
import NumberOfDays from "./NumberOfDays";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <DataContextProvider>
      <DataChart />
      <NumberOfDays />
    </DataContextProvider>
  );
}
```